# Run cron continuously except the mentioned in between time

Tags: cron

I need to run the cron from 11 AM to 11 PM (Except 12:20 PM  to 1:45 PM) daily for every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with 4 crontab entries:

```
*/5 11 * * * cmd
0-20/5 12 * * * cmd
45-59/5 13 * * * cmd
*/5 14-22 * * * cmd
```

- 1st line - run from 11:00 to 11:59 every 5 minutes
- 2nd line - run from 12:00 to 12:20 every 5 minutes
- 3rd line - run from 13:45 to 13:59 every 5 minutes
- 4th line - run from 14:00 to 22:59 every 5 minutes

**Bonus Tip:**
1st and 4th line can be combined to make it to 3 crontab entries.

```
*/5 11,14-22 * * * cmd
0-20/5 12 * * * cmd
45-59/5 13 * * * cmd
```

Comment: Don't think it is possible using a single crontab entry. Edited the answer with a solution with 3 crontab entries. Would be interesting to see if this can be simplified further.